# prettyPhoto not working with HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used following portfolio files,
http://tutorialzine.com/2011/06/beautiful-portfolio-html5-jquery/

and have added prettyphoto in each image tab, but it's not working.

All the library includes are fine.
Here is the code snippet,

under script tag,

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
        $('a[rel]').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('rel', $(this).data('rel'));
        });
    });
```

and under body tag,

```
 <li data-tags="Print Design" ><a href="assets/img/shots/1.jpg" data-rel="prettyPhoto" title="Why choose Freshology"><img src="assets/img/shots/1.jpg" alt="Illustration" /></a></li>
```

If I remove data-tags in li element, then it's working fine but it's also essential for portfolio functionality.

Please guide me for solution.
Thanks.

--

I changed from

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Now I am not getting that $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto is not a function error but still lightbox is not coming.

Comment: Can you define "not working"? Are you getting any errors in the JS console?

Comment: Yes, getting following error, $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto is not a function

Comment: @Gaurang. it's because `$` is no longer `jQuery` object after your change... What did you try to do?!